# Making "cout << obj1 + obj2 << endl;" work

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

So, I have gotten intra-class operator overloading working for obj1 + obj2:

```
fraction operator+ (fraction op);
```

Similarly, cout << obj is working by overloading operator overloading ostream:

```
ostream& operator<< (ostream& os, fraction& frac);
```

However, if I try to combine the two, all hell breaks loose.

```
fraction.cpp:77:27: error: no match for ‘operator<<’ in 
‘std::operator<< [with _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]((* & std::cout), ((const char*)"Sum: ")) 
<< f1.fraction::operator+(f2)’
```

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class fraction
{
    private:
        int n, d;

    public:
        fraction ()
        {
            this->n = 1;
            this->d = 0;
        }

        fraction (int n, int d)
        {
            this->n = n;
            this->d = d;
        }

        int getNumerator ()
        {
            return n;
        }

        int getDenominator ()
        {
            return d;
        }

        fraction operator+ (fraction op)
        {
            return *(new fraction(this->n*op.d + op.n*this->d, this->d*op.d));
        }

        fraction operator- (fraction op)
        {

            return *(new fraction(this->n*op.d - op.n*this->d, this->d*op.d));
        }

        fraction operator* (fraction op)
        {
            return *(new fraction(this->n*op.n, this->d*op.d));
        }

        fraction operator/ (fraction op)
        {
            return *(new fraction(this->n*op.d, this->d*op.n));
        }
};

ostream& operator<< (ostream& os, fraction& frac)
{
    int n = frac.getNumerator();
    int d = frac.getDenominator();

    if(d == 0 && n == 0)
        os << "NaN";
    else if(d == 0 && n != 0)
        os << "Inf";
    else if(d == 1)
        os << n;
    else
        os << n << "/" << d;
}

int main ()
{
    fraction f1(2, 3);
    fraction f2(1, 3);

    cout << f1 << " " << f2 << endl;

    /*
    cout << "Sum: " << f1+f2 << endl;
    cout << "Difference: " << f1-f2 << endl;
    cout << "Product: " << f1*f2 << endl;
    cout << "Quotient: " << f1/f2 << endl;
    */

    return 0;
}
```

Help. D:

Comment: You are leaking memory like crazy! Replace `return *(new fraction(...));` with `return fraction(...);`.

Comment: Stop using `new`. Possibly get rid of your current learning material in favour of [a decent one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/46642).

Comment: Don't do `return *(new T())` if you're trying to get an object, just do `return T()`.

Comment: Your `ostream& operator<<` doesn't return `os`.

Comment: C++ isn't java. As others have pointed out, this is leaking like a boat with a screen-door-hull.

Comment: Some other comments: I'd normally expect `fraction::fraction( int n, int d = 1 )`, to get implicit conversions from `int`.  In which case, `operator+` et al. should _not_ be members; the usual convention would be to define `operator+=` et al. as members, and then `operator+` as a free function, using `+=` in its implementation.  If you have the implicit conversion, and `operator+` is a member, `fraction( 1, 2 ) + 3` works, but `1 + fraction( 2, 3 )` doesn't.

Comment: Thanks guys, just trying to head first into some of C++'s unique features instead of playing it safe with a .display() method. As you can tell, I'm from a C and Java background. Still waiting for my copy of the "C++ Primer" to ship.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The immediate problem is that

```
ostream& operator<< (ostream& os, fraction& frac)
```

won't accept a temporary because `frac` isn't a `const` reference - change it to

```
ostream& operator<< (ostream& os, const fraction& frac)
```

`operator+` between two fractions will return a temporary which can't bind to a non-`const` reference.

There's also a **very serious memory leak** in these cases:

```
fraction operator+ (fraction )
{
   return *(new fraction(this->n*op.d + op.n*this->d, this->d*op.d)); 
}
```

`new` will return a dynamically allocated object which you then copy and return from the function.

Just do it like most people:

```
fraction operator+ (const fraction& op) const
{
   return fraction(this->n*op.d + op.n*this->d, this->d*op.d); 
}
```

(note the two extra consts and the pass by reference)

Comment: That's the immediate problem, but you should probably also point out that `operator+` et al. should be const, and that the usual convention would have all of the `fraction` arguements passed by reference to const (even though it probably doesn't make a difference with this class).

Comment: You should probably mention how his stream operator isn't returning anything.

Comment: As for "Just do like most people": I don't know of anyone who makes `operator+` a member.  Most of the time, you just inherit from something like `ArithmeticOperators<fraction>`, and get it for free.  If not, it's usually a free function using `+=` in its implementation.  (But of course, your version is perfectly fine too, and for a class this simple, maybe preferable.)

Comment: I make it a member as I didn't know any different. I've never used a language that gives you so many ways to do the same thing and most of them are wrong most of the time.

Comment: @NeilKirk No truer words have been spoken than the  last sentence in your prior comment, save to say that by-definition, something that is "wrong" is *not* a way to do something. *C++ isn't easy*. But you have an *enormous* wealth of people here that will help you if you truly put effort into it on your side. The payoff is worth it, so stick to it.

Comment: @NeilKirk In perl, there is more than one way to do it.  In C++, determine the number of ways to do something is undefined behavior.